# Не импортирует библиотеку org.telegram.telegrambots.ApiContextInitializer

Tags: java, импорт

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.ApiContextInitializer
```

Подчеркивает `ApiContextInitializer`. В чем может быть проблема, подскажите, пожалуйста. Работаю в `intellij IDEA`.

Comment: Не подключили библиотеку к проекту. В любом случае нужно внести в вопрос больше ясностей, например, как подключаете библиотеки или какой сборщик выбрали и как подключили зависимости.

Comment: Решил я сделать телеграм бота, и первым делом отправился на ютуб, создал проект в идее с использованием Maven  и прописал зависимость                                                                                  `<dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
        <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>` Т.е как я понял библиотеку я подтянул, Но вот библиотека упомянутая выше не работает, перелазил достаточно сайтов и от отчаяния пишу сюда

Comment: Ты смог решить проблему, если да, то как?

Answer (score 0):

Новые версии org.telegram.telegrambots не поддерживаю работу ApiContextInitializer (возможно начиная с 5).
Попробуйте использовать к примеру версию 3.6:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.telegram/telegrambots -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
```